# intellij idea fails to rebuild project, package lombok does not exist

Tags: intellij-idea

Project builds using maven. I invalidated IDEA cache. I reimport maven in idea. I hit rebuild project so that everything is rebuilt.

```
package lombok.extern.slf4j does not exist
```

I cannot start debugging session because of that. What can be done to fix idea?

Question 2/idea: Lets call it "reliable mode". Can we somehow disable "stuff" which keeps causing these issues all the time? I totally don't care about quick builds, as their cumulative benefit is nullified monthly, when these things stop to work, and I have to google for stuff like `-Djps.track.ap.dependencies=false` of why lombok does not work *again*.

Comment: Lombok is a compiler hack that uses internal APIs. Or you need to accept this and take the risk that things might stop working at any time, or you stop using Lombok which should avoid the issue all together.

Comment: ok, sure. I know that. It's just weird, that maven itself does not seem to be affected by this hack, and if one does sufficient amount of cache clean-up, maven reimport, restarts and rebuilds (I  still don't know what actually idea wants) the problem will disappear there, eventually, as well. If it would be possible, I'd love to sacrifice some of compilation speed, some functionality, or whatever for reliability.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Try 2021.1.1 Preview version from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+2021.1+latest+builds or install from Toolbox App. It has related Maven issues fixed.

Comment: 2021.1. But these issues with maven import are permanent for like last 2 years. From time to time it just fails, and one need to embark to route of reimporting, clearing caches, rebuilding/.../... and eventually it start working again. This time as well. After 30 minutes of frustration it works.

Comment: + all our projects uses the same lombok for very long time. It happened to me already like 5 times, that switching between branches causes idea to forgot that this library exist and stops using it for iDE and adding on class path. Nothing but full cleaning caches and restart helps. This is clearly idea bug, as I cannot explain otherwise, why should I invalidate cache for N projects because I switched git branch in one of them. And that switch does not involve any lombok change.